# C++ object method calling methods from another class that includes it's

Tags: c++

First of all, sorry for the title. I didn't know exactly how to give name to the situation I'm facing.
I am developing a project in C++ that will run over QNX (so answers that recur to Windows libraries are not good).

I have one class that holds and manipulates all my data, and a few other classes that are responsible for dealing with my UI.

The UI manipulating classes include my data class, and when they are initialized, they all get a pointer to the same data object (each one uses different parts of it, though). And the normal flow of the program is the UI receiving events from the user, and then making calls to the data class and updating itself, according to the data class replies. That all works just fine.

The problem is, sometimes it might happen that this data class object receives calls from other sorts of external events (let's say a call from a class responsible for communication), asking it to change some of it's values. After doing so, it would have to update the UI (thus, having to make a call to the UI classes).

The actual objects to all the classes (UI and data) are contained by the "main" class. But as the UI classes include the data class to be able to call it's methods, the data class including UI classes in order to be able to call their methods would fall into mutual inclusion.

The problem resumes, in a very simplistic way (I am just trying to give a visual example of the information flow), to something like this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "interface.h"
#include "data.h"

Data data_;
Interface interface_;

// Initialize all data from files, etc
data_.Init();
// Call the interface that will use all of this data
interface_.Init(&data_);
while(1);
```

**interface.h**

```
#include "data.h"
class Interface
{
    Data *data_;
    void Init(Data *data);
    void ReceiveEvent();
    void ChangeScreen (int value);
};
```

**interface.cpp**

```
#include "interface.h"

void Interface::Init(Data *data)
{
    // Get the pointer locally
    data_ = data;
}

// Function called when a (for example) a touch screen input is triggered
void Interface::ReceiveEvent()
{
    ChangeScreen(data_->IncreaseParam1());
}

void Interface::ChangeScreen (int value);
{
    // Set the value on screen
}
```

**data.h**

```
class Data
{
    int param 1;

    void Init();
    int IncreaseParam1();
    void ReceiveExternalEvent();
};
```

**data.cpp"

```
#include "data.h"

void Data::Init()
{
    // The value actually come from file, but this is enough for my example
    param1 = 5;
}

int IncreaseParam1()
{
    param1 += 5;
    return param1;
}

// This is called from (for example) a communication class that has a 
// pointer to the same object that the interface class object has
void ReceiveExternalEvent()
{
    IncreaseParam1();

    // NOW HERE IT WOULD HAVE TO CALL A METHOD TO UPDATE THE INTERFACE 
    // WITH THE NEW PARAM1 VALUE!
}
```

I hope I made myself clear enough.

Can someone please give me ideas on how to deal with this situation?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into the `observer` design pattern? https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/cpp/3

Answer (score 0):

Both `Data` and `Interface` are singletons. You expect to only have one instance of each class in existence. So:

```
Class Data {

public:
  static Data *instance;

  Data()
  {
      instance=this;
  }
  // Everything else that goes into Data, etc...
};

Class Interface {
public:
  static Interface *instance;

  Interface()
  {
      instance=this;
  }
  // Everything else that goes into Data, etc...
};
```

Now, `ReceiveExternalEvent()` will simply invoke `Data::instance->method()` and/or `Interface::instance->method()`, and so on...

This is a classical singleton design pattern.

Also, you might find some additional Google food of likely interest to you: "model view controller" and "mvc".

Comment: Thank you!

But in order to Data::instance->method()  be visible Interface methods, and Interface::instance->method(), be visible to Data methods, wouldn't it imply in mutual inclusion?

Comment: There is no mutual inclusion from the header files. You have to include all the header files you need from the .C/.cpp modules that define the methods.

Comment: But my Data and Interface cannot be defined in the same header. (I made a simple version of my problem, I actually have several interface classes).

Will the "static" modifier for the instance make it possible to be called even without inclusion?

Comment: No. Whether something is static, or not, has nothing to do with it. Only your .C translation units need to include both header files. What part of "there is no mutual includes from the header files" you did not understand?